# Fixing "Uncaught OAuthException" in IE

Tags: php, facebook

How can I fix "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown " in IE?

Comment: First, you need to show us your code. Second, you need to describe your problem more and then you should be on the way to getting some answers.

Comment: Have you tried using an active access token?

Comment: You fix it in IE in the same way you fix it for any other browser - by fixing the server side code. PHP errors should not be browser specific, unless there is some Javascript passing data to the server that does not work everywhere. Please add some code, the number of people who have earned the Clairvoyant badge is not high...

Comment: I have looked **everywhere** but I can not find any research here...

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an IE issue, you probably need to add a p3p header to your responses so it allows 3rd party cookies.

See:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx

or for php specific coding

http://www.sitepoint.com/p3p-cookies-ie6/